# Could a blade rusted by dried blood become jammed in its sheath?

Tags: weapons, metals, blood

My character forgot to clean his sword after killing a man. The blade stayed for weeks in her sheath, drying the blood.

I wrote a scene where he can't unsheathe his sword because it's "jammed". This made sense to me until today when a reader told me she is not sure of that.

Can a sword be jammed in its sheath because of rusty blood?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, corrosion can jam metal things. Especially if the sheath has metal parts on the inside. But... I would be surprised that the sword was stuck so hard that it could not be extracted from the sheath. On the other hand, proper care of weapons if one of the first things which an instructor teaches their pupil, befor even beginning to teach the handling of the weapon. During training, the instructor will ceaselessly pound proper weapon care into the head of the student. Unless she somehow learned sword fighting all by herself, it is unlikely that she forgot to clean her sword after use.

Comment: Keeping a weapon in the sheath for weeks would mean the character don't train with it. That with not cleaning the blade would mean they are terrible swordfighter and have no idea how to take care about their tools.

Comment: What does this have to do with building a fictional world? This looks like a question about an event is happening within an already built world.

Comment: Hello Erich, welcome to [worldbuilding.se]. As a reminder to everyone, [real world questions are permitted](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6161/40609) in the context of worldbuilding. To be fair to everyone else, please note, Erich, that worldbuilding has to do with the development and consistent use of rules and systems. Storybuilding is about circumstances, plot, and character choices/actions, and that's off-topic. Your question is, IMO, on-topic because it's an application-of-technology-in-my-world question. When you get a moment, please take our [tour]. Thanks!

Comment: Erich, I have actually seen (Civil War re-enactments) where a soldier had fallen, and the *scabbard* had been bent in a fall from a horse, by impact against a rock ( the guy nearly broke his leg), the sword inside was intact, but so "jammed" in place it was taken to a gunsmith to be removed.  - Just my $0.02

Comment: @Erich ParaBibin   You should read about the Zulfigar, the legendary sword of Ali that his enemies  nailed into the scabbard before they attacked him, and which he pulled so hard that  it came out of the scabbard split in 2 like a scissors. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulfiqar  If your character is as excited as Ali they are likely to pull hard enough to get the sword out of the scabbard even if it is glued inside.

Comment: I agree with JBH on this one.  Story based closes are supposed to be for when the event is determined by the personal choices of the characters.  The OP is not asking if the character in this event would choose for his sword to get stuck, but if the science regarding the interactions of the materials and timeframe in question could result in it.

Comment: I concur on the story-based, but there is no "context of worldbuilding" here for this to be justifiably reopened. For a real world question to be on topic here, there still has to be an actual *worldbuilding problem* to be solved. Otherwise, this is a perfectly mundane question fit for Quora: can a bloodied sword rust sufficiently in its scabbard so that it can't be pulled out. Give us a *worldbuilding problem*, and I'd happily vote to reopen this!

Comment: @elemtilas if we were dealing with an experienced user I wouldn't hesitate to agree - but we're dealing with a new user. Frankly, the fact that it's a "she" that's using a sword invites basic worldbuilding (pretty low percentage of swordwomen in Earth's history). What guidance would you offer for the necessary paragraph? Would a brief paragraph explaining the world the swordwoman exists in be enough? (Thanks for working with me on this.)

Comment: I think the question is specific enough and gives all the context required to provide answer. Fluff like "in my world people use swords" seems redundant to me, so I'll vote to reopen. However, it does deserve a downvote because it shows little research effort.

Comment: @JBH - no worries! I'd be looking for some kind of *difference* -- what makes the facts of this question different from what I'd expect of ordinary Earth. Something weird about the metal? Something unique about the blood? Something in the materials of the sheath? I'd actually demolish your argument about the sword wielder being a girl ;) after all, in much of human history, who is it that does much of the cooking? In an average house from ancient times up through the modern period, it's typically Mom! And through most of history, her tools have included iron knives. I'd hazard the guess...

Comment: ... that most human women through history know to keep their iron knives clean so that they don't rust. A sword is no different. Just from experience, I can say that iron won't rust enough within a fortnight or two, even if she dropped the whole bloody mess into a barrel of brine, to freeze the blade in the scabbard. It would take decades of being buried in damp earth for iron parts to freeze together (check out images of battle field relics). At best, if she poured some blood into the scabbard and rammed the bloody blade into it and left the whole mess to congeal for a month, it might be...

Comment: ...sticky, but nowhere close to being unremovable. That's why I'd be looking for some in-world details that could help give the OP a really good in-world answer. As it stands, I simply think this is a pure real world question: one of the historical weapons use and care that could best be answered in a history or weapons forum.

Comment: @elemtilas I didn't even think about cooking (that's the problem with a patriarchy, right?), and it's a good point. The average woman of the era would have a higher chance than the average man to know about knives and scabbards.

Comment: @JBH - Well, men had their iron tools as well: hay forks, scythes, spades, ploughs, hammers, and the like. *All* iron tools require special care to keep them from rusting. It's just a couple weeks isn't enough to ruin or make an iron tool useless!

Comment: @elemtilas the 'difference' to me is the act of leaving the sword bloodied up in the scabbard for weeks. Asking about sword care on a history site will probably get the answer that people cleaned their blades. Conjecture about the rate of sword blood rusting is way more interpretive than strict historical analysis of cleaning methods. I don't think that a fantasy metal or special blood is required - we allow questions about planetary system viability with perfectly vanilla Newtonian laws of motion. But, downvote from me because OP didn't research historical sword care methods.

Comment: @KeizerHarm - Actually, I think a reasonably comprehensive answer, especially from someone who studies period weapons, would touch upon more than just the obvious "they cleaned their blades". Obviously, the MC "forgot to clean her sword"! As I see it, without sòme kind of fantasy or "other" metal / blood component / etc, this question really doesn't belong in Worldbuilding. It may be interesting, but as is, off topic.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the best fit for *Worldbuilding*, but *History* probably would not take it, either. Perhaps *Outdoors* if you ask about a real-world knife or machete, but there they will tell you to take care of your tools. So:

- The word "jamming" probably does not describe the mechanism, and the blood is not "rusty" either.
- You could have a problem where drying and clotting blood "glues" the blade into the sheath. It is no good glue, but the contact area is large.
- The uncleaned blade will probably rust. It is the metal of the blade that is rusting. This might further enhance the "glue" effect by adding friction.

Comment: Outdoors would be a bad resource because most modern blades are made from stainless steel and thier sheethes from synthetic materials, they would generally not have a meaningful perspective on historical blades and sheaths.

Answer (score 0):

**His sword comes apart.**

This sword looks great and was actually quite expensive and fancy.   But it is a dress sword for parades and ceremonies, not for battle.  On pulling hard, he pulls the hilt and guard off of the short tang.

[image: sword art online]

https://science.howstuffworks.com/sword-making1.htm

This could totally happen.  Now he has a little hilt in his hand and the blade is still lodged in the sheath.  He could hold it by the sheath and do the best he can - faster than finding a big stick and better than using the hilt in his fist.  Though that might be worth something.

Comment: Good point about the ease with which decorative swords fall to pieces. A quick perusal of Youtube for sword fails demonstrates how poorly a made sword-like object can end up stuck in a scabbard. But you don't need rust or blood to act as the agent, so I don't see how you're answering the question.